# Apply 2D filters to camera output in the Game Engine

Tags: game-engine, opengl

is it possible to apply custom GLSL shader like the shaders you can set in the logic bricks called "Filter2D" to a camera that is not the main camera?

I am rendering the output of a camera in the scene to a VideoTexture. But the GLSL shader that were set as screen are not applied to that image. How can I achieve that? I want to apply a barrel distortion filter to that VideoTexture.

Thanks &
Best Regards